# Get list of user created variables

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to get a list of all variables that I have created in a lisp session. I think that this should be possible by looking at all symbols interned in common-lisp-user. But how can I get such a list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get bound variables only from `cl-user` you iterate all bound symbols with `do-symbols` and exclude the symbols, that are imported from other packages:

```
(let ((external-symbols (mapcan (lambda (pkg)
                                  (let (rez)
                                    (do-symbols (s pkg rez)
                                      (push s rez))))
                                (package-use-list (find-package 'cl-user)))))
  (do-symbols (s 'cl-user)
    (when (and (boundp s)
               (not (member s external-symbols)))
      (print s))))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `do-symbols` to find the symbols in the `common-lisp-user` package.

See [the CLHS entry for Macro DO-SYMBOLS, DO-EXTERNAL-SYMBOLS, DO-ALL-SYMBOLS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_do_sym.htm)