# How can I list all of the defined functions and global variables that are active in common lisp

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, sbcl, slime

Is it possible to determine what the current environment has defined (in the common lisp image), from the running system itself?

I am running SBCL 1.3.14 and SLIME 2016-04-19 in GNU Emacs 25.1.1.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371708/get-list-of-user-created-variables/8372023#8372023

Comment: Why do you want this info? If you are casting about for something specific, you might try `apropos`.

Comment: @sds answered the question I was asking. I was looking for a list of all functions and variables so that I could know what was active in the environment. I did not have a specific function or variable in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the list of all packages using [`list-all-packages`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_list_a.htm), and for each package you can see what goodies it export using [`do-external-symbols`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_do_sym.htm):

```
(do-external-symbols (s "SB-EXT")
  (when (fboundp s)
    (format t "~S names a function~%" s))
  (when (boundp s)
    (format t "~S names a variable~%" s)))
```

You might also want to check [`documentation`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_docume.htm):

```
(do-external-symbols (s "SB-EXT")
  (when (and (fboundp s) (documentation s 'function))
    (format t "~S names a documented function~%" s))
  (when (and (boundp s) (documentation s 'variable))
    (format t "~S names a documented variable~%" s)))
```

PS. If you are looking for something specific, you should also try [`apropos`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_apropo.htm).